# Click event to fire only on one element of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I have this layout with cards where each card has this markup:

```
 <div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="brand">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      25€/year
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-color">Buy</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost overlay-toggle">Details</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
             ...Details here...
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I click the details button I want the details div to pop over the card. I have this working as I want, but the problem is that the event fires on all the cards at once instead of just the one I clicked the button from.

This is the jQuery for the click:

```
var overlayToggle = $('.overlay-toggle');
var overlayClose = $('.close-overlay');
var overlay = $('.details');

overlayToggle.on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  overlay.css({
    'visibility': 'visible',
    'opacity': '1',
    'transform': 'scale(1)'
  });
});

overlayClose.on('click', () => {
  overlay.css({
    'visibility': 'hidden',
    'opacity': '0',
    'transform': 'scale(0)'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined `overlay` as a JQuery wrapped set that contains all the `details` elements and in each event handler, you tell the entire set to display or hide.

What you need to do is, in the event handlers, find only the `details` element that corresponds to the button that was clicked.

```js
var overlayToggle = $('.overlay-toggle');
var overlayClose = $('.close-overlay');

overlayToggle.on('click', (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();
   // Find the .details within nearest ancestor that is .card
   $(".details", $(e.target).closest(".card")).css({
    'visibility': 'visible',
    'opacity': '1',
    'transform': 'scale(1)'
  });
});

overlayClose.on('click', () => {
  overlay.css({
    'visibility': 'hidden',
    'opacity': '0',
    'transform': 'scale(0)'
  });
});
```

```css
.details { visibility:hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="brand">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      25€/year
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-color">Buy</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost overlay-toggle">Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
             ...Details here...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="brand">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      25€/year
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-color">Buy</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost overlay-toggle">Details</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
             ...Details here...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="brand">
      <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      25€/year
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-color">Buy</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost overlay-toggle">Details</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
             ...Details here...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this does what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
overlayToggle.on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(e.target).parents('.card').find('.details').css({
    'visibility': 'visible',
    'opacity': '1',
    'transform': 'scale(1)'
  });
});
overlayClose.on('click', () => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(e.target).parents('.card').find('.details').css({
    'visibility': 'hidden',
    'opacity': '0',
    'transform': 'scale(0)'
  });
});
```

You can also use like this, the problem is you haven't pointed to which details block you need to display.

Comment: Glad to help you :)